# Pythonで検索エンジンから画像スクレイピング

Tags: python, web-scraping

PythonでBing画像検索した画像を自分のPCに保存したいのですが9割以上が空のファイルになってしまいます。
どのように対処したら良いのでしょうか?また、原因は何なのか詳しい方教えて下さいませんか?
よろしくお願いします。

http://o-tomox.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/09/25/191506
のページを参考にアカウントを作ってキーを取得、
http://ykicisk.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/02/15/124841
のページのコードをapi_key="hogehoge"の部分を自分のキーに書き換え、

```
python collect_images.py -q 検索ワード -o "C:/Users/hogehoge"
```

として実行したのですが、

```
URLError
url:http://www.hogehoge.jp/img.jpg
```

のようになり、0バイトのjpg,pngなどの画像ファイルがたくさん出力され、中身のあるファイルは1割以下です。

****追記****
バージョンは2.7の64bitでOSはWin7です。Anacondaで入れたものです。

****追記2****

```
proxy_dict =  {"http":"your.proxy:8080"}
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy_dict)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

をコメントアウトし、

```
response = requests.get(url,
                        auth=(api_key, api_key), 
                        headers={'User-Agent': 'My API Robot'})#,
                        #proxies=proxy_dict)
```

として実行したところ、今まで100枚でやっていた（そのうち回収できたのは3,4枚?）ところ10枚に減らしたというところもあるのですが、10枚中5枚回収できました。
エラーのところは

```
url:http://images6.fanpop.com/image/hogehoge.jpg
Forbidden
```

のようになりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLError` が表示されていることから、ネットワーク通信時の何らかのエラーであると考えられます。

[参考にしたコード](http://ykicisk.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/02/15/124841) を見ると出力用ファイルを開いたあとにネットワーク通信を行っているため、エラー発生時にもファイルが生成されてしまい0バイトの画像ファイルがたくさん出力されているのでしょう。

`URLError` の表示と一緒に表示されているURLが正しい画像ファイルを返しているかどうかをcurlコマンドやブラウザにコピペして表示してみる等々確認してみてください。

それと、参考コードのエラー表示部分：

```
except urllib2.URLError:
    print("URLError")
```

ここを

```
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print(e.reason)
```

に書き換えて再度実行してみたらどのような結果になるでしょうか？

また、利用しているPythonのバージョンやOSなど実行環境が追記してあると、より良い回答が得やすくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。明日試してみます。

Comment: 試してみたところ

   [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

というエラーが大量発生しました。調べてみたところプロキシを設定しなければならないようですが、そのやり方がよくわからないです。コードの中で

    proxy_dict =  {"http":"your.proxy:8080"}

の部分はまだいじっていないのですがここをいじるのでしょうか?いじるとしたら具体的にどのようにすればよいのでしょうか?

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search で公開されている文書を見るかぎり、検索時にプロキシの設定は必要ないと思います。proxyに関する部分を削除してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: （ただ、プロキシ未設定が問題であるならばその部分でコケているはずなので、download_urllistが実行されている点が気になりますが…）

Comment: 少しですが改善したので本文に追記しました。ありがとうございます。
これ以上の改良は無理なのでしょうか？

Comment: 追記２のエラー出力はおそらく「403 Forbidden (閲覧禁止)」ですね。国外からのアクセスが制限されている可能性があります。参考コードでは海外のプロキシサーバを経由して画像データを転送させることでこの問題を回避しているのかもしれません。

Comment: 公開プロキシ(https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B7)は検索すれば簡単に見つかりますが、利用は自己責任です。念のため。